# Android 2.2 exception handling, catch argument null

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm wondering if anyone came across an odd behaviour.. I have try/catch block, where catch statement assigns an exception variable to enable me to handle exception properly.

What I get is ex = null in catch(Exception ex) statement.

What am I doing wrong, please?

```
public class HelloWorldAndroidActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello world!");
        try {
            ExceptionTest et = new ExceptionTest();
            et.throwExeption();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}

public class ExceptionTest {
    public String throwExeption() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("Crash!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Impossible, that's what it is.

Comment: Staring at the wrong output? Debugger replacing the value? Your `ex` being annoyed?

Comment: Sometimes weird things happen if the source and the .class files are not in sync, that could be the case here.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour using the android emulator. Can you supply further configuration information and a bit more details about how you get to this behaviour? Otherwise I agree with owlstead's last comment.

Comment: Thanks chaps. I seem to be able consistently reproduce this with any 2.2/2.3 API on emulator. Perhaps it's a more global JVM issue on my box? What's the relationship between JVM and emulator? Regarding the source classes and debug symbols being out of sync I have created a brand new project/app for reproduction and here results are still the same... LOL it's probably my ex being annoyed! :)

Comment: See also [*What if I don’t get a good answer?*](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty)

Comment: I have same situation.
Found this http://www.adarshr.com/papers/npe